# Showdialog Make the Parent Form Flicker in MONO (2.10.9)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono

I create a winform application with .NET 2.0.
And I use mono (version `2.10.9`) for none-dotnet system.

But in the mono mode, when I use "`new Form().ShowDialog()`" or just show a message box "`MessageBox.Show()`", the main form flickers.

I think when it triggers the `showdialog` method, the main form runs something like "`enable = false`" through the controls, which costs some time and the flicker.

Is there anyone have some idea to solve that?

Thanks.

btw, I am checking the code in the mono branch:
`https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/Form.cs`

hope to solve this issue!!!!!

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: sorry for miss the detail, the mono version is 2.10.9. I want to use the 3.x version, but seems that there are some bugs there, and it can't even startup my program.

Comment: report those bugs as "regression" in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: now i am too busy fixing my program, have no so much time to investigate the mono 3.x bugs.  BTW, i found that the code `Managed.Windows.Forms` in MONO main branch have never been updated for two years, i wonder if mono team have fix this issue.

Comment: the mono team doesn't fix the Managed.Windows.Forms bugs for their business anymore, but if you don't report the bugs you find, you have infinite less chances from seeing them fixed (last changes in M.W.F. 2 years ago were done by volunteers)

Comment: ok, i have reported the bug found in 3.x. And i download the latest code to update for my project, and thanks a lot

Comment: please post here the URL of the reported bug, for reference